# How to add arguments to Diagnostic Start with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, process, scripting, native

I am limited to only using native windows tools, and I need to automate opening a browser, going to a website, and then closing the browser. I'm going to use task scheduler to run the script.

I created this PowerShell script which successfully opens a browser, and closes it.
How would I go about having this open a specific webpage? Start Arguments or something else?

```
$browser = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe")
$id = $browser.Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
try {
    Stop-Process -Id $id -ErrorAction stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to kill"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start the process with the appropriate Chromium command line argument(s):

```
$browser = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe", "https://stackoverflow.com/ --new-window")
$id = $browser.Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
try {
    Stop-Process -Id $id -ErrorAction stop
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to kill"
}
```

[Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#definition)
[Run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)
[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)